# k8s: How to list all deployments versions

Tags: kubernetes

In Kubernetes how can I list all deployments versions? Also, is there a tool to compare deployment versions between two clusters (ex: dev & staging)?

Main problem: we've multiple identical development clusters, but deployment versions are not the same, so I need a way to list all deployment versions from one cluster to be able to compare it to versions from another cluster.

Answer (score 1):

**To list all deployment versions**

```
 kubectl get deployment -o=jsonpath="{range .items[*]}{'\n'}{.metadata.name}{': '}{range .spec.template.spec.containers[*]}{.image},{end}{end}" | sort
```

**To compare deployment versions between two different clusters/contexts**

```
diff --width=140 --suppress-common-lines --side-by-side \
  <(kubectl get deployment --context=[TODO] --namespace=[TODO] -o=jsonpath="{range .items[*]}{'\n'}{.metadata.name}{': '}{range .spec.template.spec.containers[*]}{.image},{end}{end}" | sort) \
  <(kubectl get deployment --context=[TODO] --namespace=[TODO] -o=jsonpath="{range .items[*]}{'\n'}{.metadata.name}{': '}{range .spec.template.spec.containers[*]}{.image},{end}{end}" | sort)
```